# How to implement a global class in django

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am currently working on a networked multiplayer game using django and django channels for websockets.  I currently have my project set up where players send data to the server which then processes that data in a "GameManager" class that processes all game logic and interactions between all players.  This works perfectly fine in my dev environment, but when I tried setting up my project for production, my global "GameManager" class does not seem to retain it's data across multiple requests.  I'm guessing that since I'm using gunicorn in my production environment, my django project is running amongst multiple processes that each have their own instance of my classes.

My question is how can I implement some sort of global class in django to handle all the game logic that will be shared across all requests?  I can't use sessions because I need this data to be shared by ALL connected clients, and I'm skeptical of using a solution such as redis because I would need to be reading/writing to it multiple times a second, so keeping it within python would help me keep things running smoothly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really redis is the solution here. It's easily able to deal with multiple reads/writes per second.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Very well, do you know of any painless methods I could use to move my classes over to Redis, or am I looking at a full rewrite of my code base